# Parse XML file in Java and output all errors

Tags: java, xml, parsing, error-handling, xml-parsing

I am currently trying to parse an XML file in Java. I have done lots of research and tried using many of the available libraries such as DOM, SAX, etc. All of these are great and have lots of options. My issue though is I want to be able to parse an entire XML file then output any errors that may be there. With SAX for example, it will parse the file, but only output the first syntax error. Is there anyway to output all errors at once like a compiler can or am I out of luck?

If this is not possible, I am attempting a work around to parse my XML file like a normal text file and grab all the opening and closing tags. Is there a simpler way to do this besides creating many conditional statements and rules?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a *syntax* error, you can't tell anything for sure about the rest of the file.

Comment: Yeah that is what I figured. Is there a way to easily grab all the xml opening and closing tags in Java? I am parsing normally, but realizing I am creating a ton of conditions and it does not seem efficient.

Comment: How do you know the closing tag is actually a closing tag if there's a syntax error? Maybe the syntax error was that the "closing tag" was supposed to be in a comment, but the comment has a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a **custom** `ErrorHandler` (as the default `ErrorHandler` throws exception on first error).

```
 public void validateXML(SAXSource source, Schema schema) throws SAXException, IOException
  {
    javax.xml.validation.Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler()
    {

      @Override
      public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException
      {
        System.err.println("Notice: " + exception.toString());
      }

      @Override
      public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException
      {
        error(exception);
      }

      @Override
      public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException
      {
        System.err.println("Error occured: " + exception.toString());
      }
    });
    validator.validate(source);
  }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answear! Thank you MRalwasser!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you will have much success finding such type of XML parsers. By definition, an XML parser should throw an exception on first error it encounters. If it doesn't, it will have no way to identify the node type or correctness of any subsequent text ...

Comment: Yeah sadly it seems that way. It makes sense from a logical point of view. I will just have to modify what I am working on to fit my needs. I appreciate the feedback though.

Comment: @vtd-xml-author: This is not correct. See my answer for details.